# WP ACF Get Attachment 'Page Link' URL on number of images in slider

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to generate a slider for my site. Each of the images (attachments) also have a custom field attached to them using the 'Page Link' option, which allows me to associate a link with each image. The code below is pulling through a link, but it is the same for each image, regardless of which one is displayed in the slider (each image should have a different link)

```
    <section class="slideshow">
        <?php 
        $images = get_field('slideshow');
        if( $images ):
        ?>
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <figure>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></h2>
                        <h4><a href="<?php the_field('url_link'); ?>">View Case Study</a></h4>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section>
```

I have also tried making the url_link field specific to the image as below, but this doesn't pull any information.

```
<h4><a href="<?php echo $image['url_link']; ?>">View Case Study</a></h4>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which field type are you using for your `slideshow` field?

Comment: @JordiNebot - I'm using the gallery field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this isn't the best use of the 'Gallery' custom field. Instead, I've turned to using the 'Repeater' field which can have sub-fields in which I can hold image, caption and link information. Code amended as follows.

```
<section class="slideshow">       
    <?php if( have_rows('slideshow_slides') ): ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('slideshow_slides') ): the_row(); 
            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $caption = get_sub_field('caption');
            $link = get_sub_field('link');
        ?>

        <figure>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
            <figcaption>
                <h2><?php echo $caption; ?></h2>
                <?php if( $link ): ?>                    
                    <h4><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">View Case Study</a></h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>
```